# Selenium/Java basic things not working with IE and FireFox on Windows

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

When I try to open `driver1.get("http://www.google.com");`, it opens the site twice and throws the error below. I then tried to go through the older versions of Selenium, none of it seems to work.

These are the versions I tried

```
Selenium: 2.53.0
Java:  "1.8.0_92"
Windows: Windows 7 Professional
FireFox: 45.2.0
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not found: 15676d46-e86c-420d-a349-b73ca0f5bb59
>   Command duration or timeout: 5.54 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'IBM263-PC07TNJV', ip: '9.124.217.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.2.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: 15676d46-e86c-420d-a349-b73ca0f5bb59
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
>       at Test.main(Test.java:19)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not found: 15676d46-e86c-420d-a349-b73ca0f5bb59
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'IBM263-PC07TNJV', ip: '9.124.217.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at .nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12704)
>       at .Dispatcher.executeAs/<(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9558)
>       at .Resource.prototype.handle(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9705)
>       at .Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9652)
>       at .WebDriverServer/<.handle(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:12517)
>       at .createHandlerFunc/<(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2054)
>       at .ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2387)
>       at .Connection.prototype.process(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1223)
>       at .RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1677)
>       at .RequestReader.prototype._processBody(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1525)
>       at .RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady(file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3999483330061689508webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1393)

I also tried the same with IE (11.0.9600.18439CO) but still I get this error during `driver1.close();`

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
>   2.53.1.0
>   Listening on port 25952
>   Only local connections are allowed
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'IBM263-PC07TNJV', ip: '9.124.217.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:25952/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
>   Session ID: 5097a6b5-66e6-4136-8551-8797496f5051
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:521)
>       at Test.main(Test.java:35)

These are the most basic and should be working? Am I missing anything?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;  

public class Test  
{  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  
   {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\SoftWareDownLoads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");  
      WebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();  
      //WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();  
       driver1.get("http://www.google.com");  
       driver1.close();  
   }  
}
```

Comment: show your full initialization code

Comment: Show all of your code

Comment: Here is the full code

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
public class Test
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver1.get("http://www.google.com");
     
        driver1.close();
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
  
    }
 }

Comment: Please add the code to your question and properly format it.

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Test
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\SoftWareDownLoads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver1.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver1.close();
    }
 }

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Test
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\SoftWareDownLoads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver1.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver1.close();
    }
 }

Comment: Have put in the code snippet now @JeffC

Comment: Please read the help on how to format as code and I would put the code at the top of your question. Those error messages are very long.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message for IE contains "Unable to get browser". A probable reason for this is that Selenium cannot find the IE driver. Can you ascertain that the path you've provided to get .exe file for IE driver is correct?
For firefox, try using
 `driver1.quit();` after `driver1.close();`. This might prevent another browser window from being launched, for whatever odd reason it is.

Comment: Nope, Anshu, thats not the issue. The path went ok. 

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'IBM263-PC07TNJV', ip: '9.109.250.255', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: It opens the browser twice.  
Why does it open the browser twice.  ? 

Both in IE as well as FireFox it opens the browser twice ..

Sometimes I can see it working ok, but then it again opens the browser twice and fails when I change the URL in the browser.

Comment: When you say "opens the browser twice", do you mean it opens 2 browser windows? Or it opens window, closes it and then opens another?

Comment: It opens the browser , does the things, 

Closes the browser. 

And then it opens an other one.

Comment: "does the things" as in launch "google.com" and quit. Does it launch the same URL second time?

Comment: When I use firefox.It opens a firefox browser, opens google.com. And then opens a new window at the end.

Comment: In my code, I have these things. 1. driver1.get("http://www.google.com"); 2.  System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver1.getTitle()); 3. WebElement element = driver1.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")); 4.  element.sendKeys("Cheese!");. 5. driver1.close();.   So with Firefox, it opens a new firefox browser, opens up google.com and types in "Cheese!" and then closes. After it does these things, it opens up a new firefox window. This new firefox window should not have been opened.

Comment: With IE, executing the same, throws this error, Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information). Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'IBM263-PC07TNJV', ip: '9.109.250.255', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDr...   The error is because of the line driver1.getTitle()

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Ashok. May I ask you to try using driver1.quit(); after driver1.close(). This might prevent another browser window from being launched, for whatever odd reason it is. Also can you parse the complete URL i.e. google.com by adding  https://www. to it

I'm just trying to work around with you as such a simple code not working is making me curious :)

Comment: Thanks Anshu, after the dirver1.quit. It closes it ok. 

Quite new to this, somehow I find it not as stable as it should be, I can see same things passing once failing once. 

The solution you provided helped me overcome my issue on Firefox, thank you for that

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not found: 3fdcc3cd-fd47-4779-9525-076ac7d4c169

Comment: For IE or for Firefox?

Comment: Firefox. Kind of fed up with this

Comment: Hmm.. That's really strange behaviour. I will be watching your question in case anyone comes up with the exact solution. All the luck!

Comment: I just tried the same code in Linux. On Linux it just was so very smooth.